# Unexpected infinite loop when counting numbers without the digit 9

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the code below, or input `1` thru `8`, I am getting the correct answer. But for input `>= 9`, I am not getting any output at all: the code runs indefinitely.

Here is my code:

```
N = int(input())
list = []
a = True
b = 1
        
while N > 0:
    for i in str(b):
        if i == '9':
            a = False
    if a == True:
        list.append(b)
        N -= 1
    b += 1
print(list[N - 1])
```

What is causing the infinite loop for `N >= 9`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `N` is 9, you get to a point at which `b == 9`. This causes `a` to be set to `False` once and for all. That means that the decrement `N -= 1` never happens after that and the loop runs forever.

A simple fix is to ensure that `a` is reset at every iteration:

```
N = 9
list = []
b = 1
        
while N > 0:
    a = True
    for i in str(b):
        if i == '9':
            a = False
    if a == True:
        list.append(b)
        N -= 1
    b += 1
print(list[N - 1])
```

That being said, the whole thing can be written more elegantly, a.k.a. pythonically:

```
N = int(input())
b = 0
        
while N > 0:
    b += 1
    if '9' in str(b):
        continue
    N -= 1
print(b)
```

Notice that you don't need a list if you only want the nth number without nines. And using the name `list` shadows the built-in class, so is generally frowned upon.

For a more general solution, I would write a generator of numbers that don't contain nines:

```
def nonines():
    b = 0
    while True:
        b += 1
        if '9' not in str(b):
            yield b
```

This generator can run effectively forever, producing numbers that contain no nines, since python has unlimited precision integers.

You can get the `n`th element of the generator with something like

```
for _, b in zip(range(n), nonines()):
    pass
print(b)
```

Or more succinctly:

```
from itertools import islice

b = next(islice(nonines(), n - 1, n))
```

You can use a similar technique to get a list of the first `n` elements:

```
lst = [b for _, b in zip(range(n), nonines())]
```

Or

```
lst = list(islice(nonines(), n))
```

The generator itself can be simplified significantly using `itertools`:

```
from itertools import count

def nonines():
    for b in count(1):
        if '9' not in str(b):
            yield b
```

Or

```
def nonines():
    yield from (b for b in count(1) if '9' not in str(b))
```

Comment: Thanks sir. Would you like to suggest me some book or course to follow,from which i can learn python as a beginner to very advanced? .

Comment: @Dev.Professor. The tutorial in the python documentation is pretty great. It takes a bit of elbow grease to get through all the details, but it's very much worth it in my opinion.

Comment: Ok sir.But, apart of that is there any book you can suggest me so that i can buy and read for much detail in python? It will be a great help.

Comment: @Dev.Professor. The official python documentation has a tutorial that is free. I would not recommend buying a book. Just go through the tutorial and practice a lot. That's pretty much how I learned python.

Comment: Can you plz share the direct link to that sir ?

Comment: @Dev.Professor. It would have taken you less than a minute of Google to find this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/. Independent research is a very important skill as a programmer.

Comment: Already done that. And thank you sir for your kind assistance.